# Unable to run the default python code for MCP4725 example

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am working with `MCP4725`. I was working on this quite some time without any issues but currently even the default example given in the [GitHUb Repository](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP4725/blob/master/examples/simpletest.py) keeps throwing this error.

```
Press Ctrl-C to quit...
Setting voltage to 0!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "simpletest.py", line 21, in <module>
    dac.set_voltage(0)
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_MCP4725/MCP4725.py", line 68, in set_voltage
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 129, in writeList
File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 306, in 
write_i2c_block_data
IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error
```

I tried this command `i2cdetect -y 1`

```
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: 60 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I checked the connections, everything looks good. Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your I2C address.As you are using example code ,in example code address is(0x62) but in your case it is (0x60).So just change this ,it will work properly.
For your convenience,i am providing my code which is perfectly working with my hardware.

```
import Adafruit_MCP4725
import time
dac=Adafruit_MCP4725.MCP4725(address=0x60)
try:
  while True:
     for x in range(0,4096,1):
        dac.set_voltage(x)
        vlt=x/4096*5.0
        print(x,vlt)
        time.sleep(1)
except Exception:
  print("issue")
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

uninstall smbus and then again install Adafruit_GPIO again and then try,
and don't use simply dac.set_voltage(0) instaed try to use

```
for i in range (0,100,1)
  dac.set_voltage(i)
```

Comment: It appears that the `MCP4725` is not responding to the `Raspberrry p` and not the other way round. How do I resolve this?

Comment: @Jasmine,i provided my code which is working with my MCP4725 dac. Go through it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue. I changed the address to 0x60 and also had issues with the jumpers used for connection. Thank you for the help.